# reverse double linked cilcurar list

Tags: c++

Suppose we have two double-bonded cyclic list. We would like reverse them in O (1). Then we want to be able to write such letters. (O (n) (in reverse order, because they were reversed). Would be easy, but we have to be able to combine these lists into one and write in them. Let me give a few examples:

Let's say that you have two list on input. There are avaible to "operations":
join ( the example show how it works), display and reverse:
OK:
First example:

```
L1: a b c d e 
L2: f g h i j 
Display L1 ( result: )  a b c d e
Join L1 L2 ( attach the second to the end of the first) 
Display L1 :  a b c d e f g h i  j
Reverse L1 ( reversing )
Display L1 : j i h g f e d c b a
```

And second:

```
L1 a b c 
L2 d e f 
L3 w
Reverse L1
Join L1 L2
Display L1: c b a d e f 
Join L1 L3:
Display L1 : c b a d e f w
```

Time complexity for join and reverse is O(1), for Display is obviously O(n).

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to implement this operation.

Comment: @user3487199 That's too broad ... You are expected to show at least what you tried on your own, and may ask about particular problems you have with your implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reversing a cyclic double linked list is straight forward using one additional parameter: **order**

Each node of a double linked list has two pointers: **forward** and **backward**

- if **order** is 1, we consider **forward** to be the pointer to the
  next element
- if **order** is -1, we consider **backward** to be the pointer to the
  next element

We also keep track of the end_point and the start_point of the linked list. Reversing the list is basically swapping start_point and end_point and reversing order

```
order = -1 * order
tmp = start_point 
start_point  = end_point
end_point = tmp
```

Merging the lists is not different from merging usual double linked lists, but you have to take into account the order. You basically have 3 cases to handle:

1. both are moving forward
2. both are moving backward
3. one is moving forward while the other is moving backward

Comment: Why not a `bool order;` and `order = !order;`?

Comment: using a boolean is also an option. I like the -1, 1 idea because it can be related to a speed. it's just a personal preference, nothing more.

Comment: That's a very good reason. =]

Comment: Mhm, but How to handle this cases? ( I'm asking for 3. cases)

Comment: Additionally, my list has head, so what should I do with head?

Comment: well your head is initially your start_point, your end_point would be the element before it in the list :)

Comment: If both list have the same direction, you just merge them like you would usually do in O(1). otherwise, you will have to reverse one list the old way in O(n) then merge them as in case 1. or 2.