# particular case of merge double linked list

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose we have two double-bonded cyclic list. We would like reverse them in O(1). Then we want to be able to write such letters. (O(n) (in reverse order, because they were reversed). Would be easy, but we have to be able to combine these lists into one and write in them. Let me give a few examples:

Let's say that you have two list on input. There are available to "operations": join (the example show how it works), display and reverse: OK: First example:

```
L1: a b c d e 
L2: f g h i j 
Display L1 ( result: )  a b c d e
Join L1 L2 ( attach the second to the end of the first) 
Display L1 :  a b c d e f g h i  j
Reverse L1 ( reversing )
Display L1 : j i h g f e d c b a
```

And second:

```
L1 a b c 
L2 d e f 
L3 w
Reverse L1
Join L1 L2
Display L1: c b a d e f 
Join L1 L3:
Display L1 : c b a d e f w
```

Consider:

Reversing a cyclic double linked list is straight forward using one additional parameter: `order`

Each node of a double linked list has two pointers: forward and backward

- if order is 1, we consider forward to be the pointer to the next element
- if order is -1, we consider backward to be the pointer to the next element

We also keep track of the end_point and the start_point of the linked list. Reversing the list is basically swapping start_point and end_point and reversing order

```
order = -1 * order
tmp = start_point 
start_point  = end_point
end_point = tmp
```

Merging the lists is not different from merging usual double linked lists, but you have to take into account the order. You basically have 3 cases to handle:

1. both are moving forward
2. both are moving backward
3. one is moving forward while the other is moving backward

How to implement?
this case one is moving forward while the other is moving backward

Comment: I would implement iterators, which makes all parts of this _very_ trivial.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean. I have to do it in O(1) time ( as I wrote it int first post)

Comment: Merging two lists where one is moving forward and one is moving backwards cannot be done in O(1) time.  Or rather, it can, but the way to do it is quite silly and I doubt it's what you're looking for.  I think you have partially misunderstood a requirement.

Comment: take a look at this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22915037/reverse-double-linked-cilcurar-list/22915720?noredirect=1#22915720

Comment: Yes, in _that_ question, the merge is an O(n) step, not O(1).  Either merge or reverse will have to be an O(n) operation, they can't both be O(1) (in any sane implementation)

Comment: The more I read your question, the more I think "this assignment" is looking for the insane implementation, where you tell the direction of "next" and "prev" by comparing to the node you came from, vaguely like an xor linked list

Comment: Have you noticed that the display can do the right things. She works in time O (n)?

Comment: I am aware that the `Display` functionality is O(n).  That doesn't change any of my claims.